# How to get record where find_in_set from a comma saperate string.[MySql]

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a comma separate string like "1,2,3" and a column in table is also contain comma separate value like "1,2,4,5,3" how to get all records that match any value to any value.

for example

- id---category
- 1---1,2,4,5
- 2---1,2,3,6
- 3---2,3,5

If I search for string "1,2,3" then I should get record the category contains 1 or 2 or 3 or 1,2 or 1,3 or 2,3 or 1,2,3. It should not return the duplicate value where as we can group them.

Is it possible to get all record with a single query.

Comment: Best way is to normalize the column category

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store lists in strings, especially lists of numbers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from table where category IN (1,2,3);
```

Comment: Please check this url: https://paiza.io/projects/DGtU5FVbM5uhWwqE4p4MIw?language=mysql

Comment: Execute the queries:                                                                                     
create table Test(id integer, title varchar(100));
insert into Test(id, title) values(1, "1,2,3");
insert into Test(id, title) values(2, "1,4,5");
insert into Test(id, title) values(3, "4,5");
select * from Test where title IN (1,2);

Comment: Please answer with authority -- "try this" means potentially iterating towards an answer. SO is not a forum.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be storing lists of ids in strings.  Here are reasons why:

- Values should be stored using the correct type.  int <> string.
- SQL has lousy string processing functions.
- Foreign keys should be properly declared.
- SQL will not be able to optimize these queries.
- SQL has a great way to store lists.  It is called a *table* not a *string*.

But, sometimes you are stuck with someone else really, really, really, really, really bad data modeling decisions.  You can do something, using regular expressions:

```
where category regexp replace($string, ',', '|')
```

or perhaps more accurately:

```
where concat(',', category, ',') regexp concat(',', replace($string, ',', ',|,'), ',')
```